# How to replace code in a text document?

Tags: c#, winforms

What I would like to do is write some values to a text document. The values are values from numericUpDown objects.

Example:
One of the NumericUpDown is a score. I would like to do is change the text in the text document after a line of text. The text is a description what the values behind the lines are. In the text file is a line with "Score: score_value" and that score_value should be the value of the Score NummericUpDown.

I think that I should make lines in txt in the same order as the Winform, but I'm not sure what is best. The only thing that it's working now is writing and replacing the first line:

```
private void Option_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Game_option_values = Score.Value.ToString();

            System.IO.StreamWriter Game_options = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"link to file");
            Game_options.WriteLine(Game_option_values);

            Game_options.Close();
            Option_Save.Enabled = false;
        }
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If the text is not too big, just read it, call String.Replace, and save again.

Comment: What is the ultimate use for the text file? Is it for human consumption, are you planning to load values from file as well as saving, etc?

Comment: I would like to get the values again if the Game Options are opened again.  and replace the Winform Values by the text values.

The number of values is 7 btw.

Comment: I achieved the values to text now. How could I get the values from the text and replace the values in the WinForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is small, you can copy the whole text into memory and write it back to the file

```
string Game_option_values = Score.Value.ToString();
string text = File.ReadAllText(path); // Read all text to memory
text = text.Replace("score_value", Game_option_values); // replace the string with value from Form
File.WriteAllText(path, text); // Write it back to file
```

If the file is big, I would recommend to create a copy as the source, and rewrite it back to the original file. (Because overwriting the original file alone may destroy everything)

```
string Game_option_values = Score.Value.ToString();
string newpath = path + ".bak"; 
File.Copy(path, newpath); // copy to new file
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newpath)) // open the new file
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false)) // overwrite the original file
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine(); // read per line, so it does not consume memory too much
        line = line.Replace("score_value", Game_option_values); // replace the string with the value from Form
        sw.WriteLine(line); // write per line
    }
}
// Then you can delete the new file
```

Answer (score 0):

To write 7 different string values into text document in separate lines

```
        string[] multiple_values = new string[7];
        // ...
        // code to store values in multiple_values
        // ...
        File.WriteAllLines(@"link to file", multiple_values);
```

To read previously saved string values from text document

```
        string[] multiple_values = null;
        multiple_values = File.ReadAllLines(@"link to file");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked about your use case is that reading plain text files isn't the easiest way to load and save settings. It's conceptually simple but you spend way too much time reinventing wheels when there are already great wheels available to you.

You have easier options, including ways to validate data and handle more complicated data structures. I'd start with one of these two approaches:

1. Application and user settings. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx))
2. Create a settings class and serialize it to XML ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244(v=vs.110).aspx)) or JSON ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx)). There is a more customizable XML serializer as well ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)) but the DataContractSerializer seems the better fit when you don't need to match a specific predefined XML schema, but just want some format that stores your data.

If you had more complex data storage needs I'd point you to Entity Framework and a localdb SQL store, but that would be huge overkill here.